# How to access local SaMBa share from WAN

Tags: networking, vpn, lan, smb

I have a local machine running OpenMediaVault. There's a SMB share set up on it which is accesible from LAN.

Sometimes there's a need for me to access data on that share from outside of my LAN. What are the ways to make that possible? And which is the best?

Right now I see 2 ways:

- Set up a VPN for my LAN. I see a few problems with it: I don't want the whole LAN to be accesible from outside, but I guess this is configurable (is it?); I also use a VPN for my work already, so there might be a need to access both my home VPN and work VPN at the same time, is it possible?
- Just plainly allow access to SMB from outside by allowing access through my router's firewall. The main concern with this is security, what would be the proper way to set it up?

I also consider setting up a reverse-proxy (because I have some other resources that i want to make accessible from outside) and using domain name for outside access (if that's relevant).

I am not asking for detailed step-by-step instruction, but just for the info about the best options and, maybe, some general advice to avoid mistakes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Set up a VPN for my LAN. I see a few problems with it: I don't want the whole LAN to be accesible from outside, but I guess this is configurable (is it?)

Your VPN server will be acting as a router, and as a router it will have a firewall, and you can define whatever policies you like in the form of firewall rules. For example, if you set up a VPN on some Linux machine, it's just a matter of using regular iptables `FORWARD` rules.

You also don't need to route the entire LAN address range through the VPN – you can advertise a single-host "/32" route perfectly fine. (This will even have advantages in case of IP range collision, as the "/32 via VPN" route will have priority.)

You'll want to set up both – the routing and the firewall – though only the latter is the actual security measure.

> I also use a VPN for my work already, so there might be a need to access both my home VPN and work VPN at the same time, is it possible?

In theory yes, as long as the relevant IP address ranges do not overlap (and it may be possible even if they do overlap). Most VPN clients work like plain virtual network interfaces that integrate into regular IP routing – some networks go via VPN1, others go via VPN2, the rest goes via Ethernet default gateway.

In practice, it highly depends on the software being used for your work VPN. Some corporate VPN apps do additional behind-the-scenes configuration beyond just typical IP routing tables (e.g. Cisco AnyConnect comes to mind with its deliberate blocking of local traffic) – a bit like the "kill switch" features you find in commercial VPN services.

> Just plainly allow access to SMB from outside by allowing access through my router's firewall. The main concern with this is security, what would be the proper way to set it up?

This might not always work outright, as some ISPs even today block the SMB ports (139/445) in order to prevent the spread of Windows SMB-based worms from 15 years ago. That aside, "security" is at minimum *two* separate concerns:

- **Software** security (exploits): A recent version of Samba should be okay, as long as you keep it up-to-date – it's mainly Windows that used to suffer from security holes (though most of those were in Windows' SMBv1 server code, but I wouldn't trust the SMBv2/3 server either). That being said, I'd still use AppArmor as a safety net even for Samba.
- **Transport** security (snooping on your data or passwords): It's not great. Having the server insist on SMBv3 with SMB encryption would be the bare minimum... but it's still not very secure against snooping if you use NTLM authentication. (Not to mention that it will *quickly* become a popular target for botnets trying to crack SMB passwords.)

  So even if the server is standalone without AD, you'd still want to set up Kerberos authentication for any meaningful security. (Kerberos *can* be done without AD, just with a small krb5kdc service, and Windows clients can talk to it – but using it does rule out pretty much 100% of Android or iOS apps.)

  The situation may improve in the future as SMB-over-QUIC becomes generally available in Windows (and maybe one day in Samba too, although it'll take 100 more years for it to work with non-PC clients).

So in short, you probably **don't want to** expose SMB, and certainly not if you want secure access from phone apps (non-Windows/Linux systems).

**SFTP** (the SSH file transfer subprotocol) is a better choice here, as it's a bit more secure even when password authentication is in use (and the even more secure 'public key' authentication is easy to set up), and OpenSSH is considerably better hardened against exploits than even Samba.

The OpenMediaVault machine probably already has an SSH server running, and there are good SFTP clients for various platforms – e.g. WinSCP on Windows.

> I also consider setting up a reverse-proxy (because I have some other resources that i want to make accessible from outside) and using domain name for outside access (if that's relevant).

Reverse proxies mostly only deal with HTTP(S) (and sometimes other TLS-based services). They can be useful for exposing an HTTP-based webapp or two – like the OpenMediaVault web GUI – but when it comes to SMB they wouldn't be able to provide anything beyond dumb data relaying – no different from exposing the SMB server directly.

Comment: Your answer is on-point and very detailed. Thank you so much!